# how to redirect page of login page to index page in server side c#?

Tags: javascript, c#

I am new to developing a web application or website. Currently, I am working on the Login page, I want to redirect from Login to Index page. I am using c# on the server-side, I want to transfer after checking the credentials of the user in the DB. I tried `Response.Redirect` and `Server.Transfer` but it does not work. It always return this error on the Console of the Chrome `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)`  and when I click it, this is what inside.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Parameter: users not found.
   場所 System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection)
   場所 System.Web.Services.Protocols.UrlParameterReader.Read(HttpRequest request)
   場所 System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   場所 System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

This is my code on C#.

```
 [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void LogMeIn(string users, string pass) {

        try
        {
            string stmt = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbllogin WHERE userName = @user AND passWord = @pass";
            int count = 0;

            using (MySqlConnection thisConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString()))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmdCount = new MySqlCommand(stmt, thisConnection))
                {
                    cmdCount.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", users);
                    cmdCount.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);
                    thisConnection.Open();
                    count = Convert.ToInt32(cmdCount.ExecuteScalar());
                    if (count > 0)
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/default/index.htm", false);                    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException tEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tEx.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

And this is on Javascript.

```
function LoginMeIn(username, password) {
    //var xdata = "{'users':'" + username.toString()
    //          + "','pass':'" + password.toString()
    //          + "'}";
    var xdata = { "users": username.toString(), "pass": password.toString() };
    console.log(xdata);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '../WebService/userLogin.asmx/LogMeIn',
        data: JSON.stringify(xdata),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {

        },
        error: function (e) {
           // $("#divResult").html("Something Wrong.");
        }
    });
}
```

Any Help will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance and Regards.

Comment: You won't be able to redirect via web method. Your option is to get that count back into the js and then use `window.location = "someurl"` to redirect the user

Comment: @Izzy That is not secure sir, If someone disabled the javascript that won't work. That is why I am trying to redirect on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
   return RedirectToAction("ActionName","ControllerName",Action Parameters)
```

You can see the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)

Comment: This is not MVC sir.

Comment: Your project not MVC?

Comment: Yes Sir. Actually, this is a template that I downloaded on the internet and try to create  a web application for the first time, I just open it as `File->Open->Website` and run it. not an MVC project I think.

Comment: Could this help you?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.redirect?view=netframework-4.8